# VCPKG: Как зафиксировать версии зависимостей?

Tags: vcpkg, пакетный-менеждер

В проекте есть `vcpkg.json` вида

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg/master/scripts/vcpkg.schema.json",
    "name": "grpc-tests",
    "version-semver": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": [
        {"name": "protobuf"},
        {"name": "grpc"}
    ]
}
```

Как указать, что мне нужно `grpc` версии `1.44`?

Answer (score 0):

В `vcpkg.json` есть поле `baseline` - указатель на хеш комита от которого искать зависимости.

В списке `dependencies` для каждой зависимости нужно указать поле `version>=...`

Проблемы `vcpkg`: для фиксации нужно указывать АБСОЛЮТНО ВСЕ зависимости с их версиями(включая зависимости зависимостей).

Пример неполного `vcpkg.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version-semver": "0.0.1",
  "builtin-baseline": "acc3bcf76b84ae5041c86ab55fe138ae7b8255c7",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "boost",
      "version>=": "1.79.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "tbb"
    },
    {
      "name": "protobuf",
      "version>=": "3.21.4"
    },
    {
      "name": "grpc",
      "version>=": "1.48.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "qt5-base",
      "version>=": "5.15.5"
    },
    {
      "name": "jsoncons",
      "version>=": "0.168.7"
    },
    {
      "name": "rocksdb",
      "version>=": "6.27.3"
    }
  ]
}
```